# C++ Array using string thats read in

Tags: c++

my program is reading in 2 text files, one is going into an array and one is priming read normally. The one that is being read into an array has an item code, price, quantity, and item name. When the item code matches with the code on the other text document I need to get the price associated with it and cant figure out how.

```
while (!purchasesFile.eof())
{
    purchasesFile >> PurchaseItem >> purchaseQty;


    cout << purchaseNum << "  " << PurchaseItem << "  " << setw(4) << 
    purchaseQty << "  @ " << dollarSign << endl;

    int n = 0;  
        if (inventoryRec[n].itemCode != PurchaseItem)
        {
            inventoryRec[n+1];
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << inventoryRec[n].itemPrice << endl;
            inventoryRec[n+1];
        }

    if (PurchaseItem == inventoryRec[itemCount].itemCode)
    {
        inventoryRec[itemCount].itemOnHand - purchaseQty;
        purchaseAmount = inventoryRec[itemCount].itemPrice * purchaseQty;

        cout << purchaseAmount << "  " << 
       inventoryRec[itemCount].itemOnHand;

        purchaseCount++;
    }


    purchasesFile >> purchaseNum;
}
purchasesFile.close();
```

Comment: FYI: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/2486888)

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: When the item codes match I cant figure how to get the price that is in the same array spot as the item code. Current output https://gyazo.com/7296629f96adb493bfdad8027d06b1fb

Comment: use std::vector. Life always goes better with std::vector

Answer (score 1):

There are several statements in your code that do nothing:

```
inventoryRec[n+1];

inventoryRec[itemCount].itemOnHand - purchaseQty;
```

What you are looking for is probably something like the STL map

```
typedef struct inventory_item_t {
    inventory_item_t(const std::string& item_code, double price, int quantity) :
        item_code(item_code),
        price(price),
        quantity(quanity) { }

    std::string item_code;
    double price;
    int quantity;
} inventory_item_t;

typedef std::map<std::string, inventory_item_t> inventory_items_t;

inventory_items_t inventory_items;

inventory_items.insert(make_pair("item1", inventory_item_t("item1", 1.0, 1)));
inventory_items.insert(make_pair("item2", inventory_item_t("item2", 1.1, 2)));
inventory_items.insert(make_pair("item3", inventory_item_t("item3", 1.2, 3)));

inventory_items_t::iterator inventory_item = inventory_items.find("item1");

if(inventory_item != inventory_items.end()) {
    std::cout << "Inventory Item found - item_code: ["
              << inventory_item->first
              << "], price: ["
              << inventory_item->second.price
              << "]"
              << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Inventory Item not found" << std::endl;
}
```